# Need little help to understand the flow of the code ? i don't understand how routine-end in the output comes in between the other output statements

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

Trying to understand the flow of goroutines so i wrote this code only one thing which i am not able to understand is that how routine-end runs between the other go routines and complete a single go routines and print the output from the channel at the end.

```
import(
    "fmt"
)


func add(dataArr []int,dataChannel chan int,i int ){
    var sum int
    fmt.Println("GOROUTINE",i+1)
    for i:=0;i<len(dataArr);i++{
        sum += dataArr[i]
    }
    fmt.Println("wRITING TO CHANNEL.....")
    dataChannel <- sum

    fmt.Println("routine-end")
}


func main(){
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    dataChannel := make(chan int)
    dataArr := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    for i:=0;i<len(dataArr);i+=3{

        go add(dataArr[i:i+3],dataChannel,i)
    }   
    fmt.Println("came to blocking statement ..........")
    fmt.Println(<-dataChannel)

    fmt.Println("main() end")

}
```

```
output

main() started
came to blocking statement ..........
GOROUTINE 1
wRITING TO CHANNEL.....
routine-end
GOROUTINE 4
wRITING TO CHANNEL.....
6
main() end
```

Comment: The thing i am not able to understand is that how a goroutine gets completed since it got blocking statement see the add function it got "dataChannel <- sum " but still the line below it gets exectued HOW ?

Comment: Why is it unexpected that `routine-end` appears mixed into the output? The goroutines run concurrently to `main`, so their output can appear with many different interleavings.

Comment: It's unblocked by the `<-dataChannel` read in main.

Comment: Yeah since it is unblocked by <-dataChannel why the output of that statement comes in end ?

Comment: Because those two bits of code run concurrently and the output can be in any order. Also the goroutines might not get a chance to execute fully, so some of their output can appear to be missing.

Comment: let me tell you what i think how this code runs ,please correct me

Comment: first main started then we made a channel after that 3 go routines had been initiated then we got the "  fmt.Println("came to blocking statement ..........")
" line after that main get blocked due to next blocking statement so other go routines will get the chance to run , so let say 1 go routine runs it prints " GOROUTINE 1" then a print statement and then a blocking statement comes so after this point i am not able to understand weither main go routine runs or the others if the others how the "routine-end " got printed

Comment: The runtime can switch from one goroutine to another at any point, not just at blocking statements and returns. Maybe that's your misunderstsanding.

Comment: okay so how we would be able to understand which gets completed or which is not ? is there any to understand the flow of goroutines or they can be random all the time.

Comment: goroutines are concurrent, and will execute independently when there is no explicit coordination given. There is no "flow" to understand, either you synchronize things, or they are concurrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop launches 3 goroutines that invoke the `add` function.

In addition, `main` itself runs in a separate "main" goroutine.

Since goroutines execute concurrently, the order of their run is typically unpredictable and depends on timing, how busy your machine is, etc. Results may differ between runs and between machines. Inserting `time.Sleep` calls in various places may help visualize it. For example, inserting `time.Sleep` for 100ms before "came to blocking statement" shows that all `add` goroutines launch.

What you may see in your run typically is that one `add` goroutine launches, adds up its slice to its `sum` and writes `sum` to `dataChannel`. Since `main` launches a few goroutines and immediately reads from the channel, this read gets the `sum` written by `add` and then the program exists -- because **by default main won't wait for all goroutines to finish**.

Moreover, since the `dataChannel` channel is unbuffered and `main` only reads one value, the other `add` goroutines will block on the channel indefinitely while writing.

---

I do recommend going over some introductory resources for goroutines and channels. They build up the concepts from simple principles. Some good links for you:

- [Golang tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)
- https://gobyexample.com/ -- start with the Goroutines example and do the next several ones.

Comment: Now i understand that as soon as first add goroutine launches it got the blocking statement and then main started running other goroutines since all the blocking statement too finally main go the chance again to run and got value from channel and ends it....